# PHP Contact form not delivering mail because of HTML

Tags: php

I'm not receiving mail from this. I made and ran a mailtest.php file which worked fine, the mail showed up in my inbox, so think it's something wrong with the html code below.

Here's the html:

```
    <!--start form-->

    <section id="nicdark_parallax_2" class="nicdark_section nicdark_imgparallax nicdark_contact1_img2">
        <div class="nicdark_focus">            
            <div class="nicdark_filter blue center">

                <div class="nicdark_size_extrabig nicdark_border_white">


                    <!--start nicdark_container-->
                    <div class="nicdark_container nicdark_clearfix">


                        <div class="grid grid_12 percentage">
                            <!--content-->
                            <div class="nicdark_space_block30"></div>
                            <h2 class="white">SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER</h2>
                            <div class="nicdark_space_block20"></div>
                            <div class="nicdark_divider small"><span class="nicdark_bg_white"></span></div>
                            <div class="nicdark_space20"></div>

                            <div class="nicdark_focus nicdark_width_percentage25">
                                <div class="nicdark_marginleft10 nicdark_marginright10 nicdark_disable_marginleft_iphoneland nicdark_disable_marginleft_iphonepotr">
                                    <input class="nicdark_bg_transparent nicdark_border_bottom_white white medium subtitle" type="text" placeholder="Name" size="200">       
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nicdark_focus nicdark_width_percentage25">
                                <div class="nicdark_marginleft10 nicdark_marginright10 nicdark_disable_marginleft_iphoneland nicdark_disable_marginleft_iphonepotr">
                                    <input class="nicdark_bg_transparent nicdark_border_bottom_white white medium subtitle" type="text" placeholder="Email" size="200">       
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nicdark_focus nicdark_width_percentage25">
                                <div class="nicdark_marginleft10 nicdark_marginright10 nicdark_disable_marginleft_iphoneland nicdark_disable_marginleft_iphonepotr">
                                    <input class="nicdark_marginbottom20_iphoneland nicdark_marginbottom20_iphonepotr nicdark_bg_transparent nicdark_border_bottom_white white medium subtitle nicdark_calendar hasDatepicker" placeholder="City" type="text" value="" id="dp1418373226329">       
                                </div>       
                            </div>
                            <div class="nicdark_focus nicdark_width_percentage25">
                                <div class="nicdark_marginleft10 nicdark_marginright10 nicdark_disable_marginleft_iphoneland nicdark_disable_marginleft_iphonepotr">
                                    <!--<input class="nicdark_btn fullwidth nicdark_border_white nicdark_bg_transparent medium white title" type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE">-->    
                                    <a class="nicdark_mpopup_ajax nicdark_outline nicdark_btn fullwidth nicdark_border_white nicdark_bg_transparent medium white title" href="submit-message.html">SUBSCRIBE</a>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="nicdark_space30"></div>   

                            <!--end content-->
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <!--end nicdark_container-->

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>

    <!--end form-->
```

Scratching my head... Thanks in advance for any help!
Question was marked as duplicate, read through [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail) but still stuck?

Comment: In the HTML snippet you included, I don't see a `<form>` element. Also, it doesn't look like your `<input>` fields are named

Comment: That did it! Thanks Chris!